# Get the mouse click position on a 3d div

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d, rotation

I tried this:

```js
function getPosition(e) {
  var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  return {
    x,
    y
  }
}
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "ID: " + event.target.id + "<br> X: " + getPosition(event).x + " Y: " + getPosition(event).y;
});
```

```css
body {
  perspective: 400px;
  margin: 0;
}

#test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
}

#info {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
<div style="margin-top: 10%;">
  <div id="test">

  </div>
</div>
```

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2om9je7/23/)

but it does just work without a 3D Rotation. If I click for example in the bottom right corner of the red div, then it should give me back something arround (because you never hit the corner exact) X: 300px and Y: 300px. But this works just when the element is with no rotation. So how can I get the clicked Position with 3d rotation? (if the rotation changes, then it must work too!)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow @Bamba675. Please add the code snippet that you have tried, which can help the potential helpers here.

Comment: id added some code

Comment: I added some code